# CustomerID that bought items in the current month and previous month

Tags: sql-server

I'm having trouble working on this query. I have a table that store customer id and date item was purchase as follow (This is the result im trying to get):

```
CustomerID  PurchaseDate
------------------------
1              08/10/2018
1              07/15/2018
2              08/15/2018
2              08/15/2018
```

I'm trying to create a monthly report where I also want customerID to be listed if they purchase something the previous month.

```
select CustomerId, PurchaseDate 
From Orders
Where PurchaseDate between '08/01/18' and '08/31/18' --- can't be changed
```

I trying to get the results above to include customerid 1 with purchasedate of the previous month.  I tried adding the following but I will get list

```
select CustomerId, PurchaseDate 
From Orders
Where PurchaseDate between '08/01/18' and '08/31/18' --- can't be changed
or PurchaseDate between '07/01/18' and '07/31/18' ----
```

but this will include list of customer that bought purchased and item for the previous month even if they didn't purchase anything for the current month.Any suggestion? I will gladly appreciated it . Thanks!

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Thanks just changed it to sql-server

Answer (score 0):

You could use EXISTS:

```
select CustomerId, PurchaseDate 
From Orders o
Where PurchaseDate between '08/01/18' and '08/31/18'
 AND EXISTS (select *
             From Orders o1
             Where PurchaseDate between '07/01/18' and '07/31/18'
               and o.CustomerId = o1.CustomerId)
```

--

**EDIT:**

You should use `JOIN` then:

```
SELECT o1.CustomerId, o1.PurchaseDate, o2.PurchaseDate
FROM Orders o1
JOIN Orders o2
  ON o1.CustomerId = o2.CustomerId
Where o1.PurchaseDate between '08/01/18' and '08/31/18'
  AND o2.PurchaseDate between '07/01/18' and '07/31/18'
```

Comment: Hello Lukasz thanks for the suggestion I'm trying to understand the first part of the query : 'select 1 '-----  is this selecting the first record?

Comment: @SQLnoob `SELECT 1` is just placeholder it could be anything `SELECT *` for example. EXISTS checks existence of rows, not actual values.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz for the explanation. I tried the query and although it select the customer ID 1 with purchasedate of 8/10/2018 . Is there a way to display purchase date for the previous month too as well as customer that purchase something for the current month?    so the result will show CustomerID1 PurchaseDate '08/10/2018' and CustomerID1 PurchaseDate '07/15/2018'

Comment: @SQLnoob Yes, using JOIN

Comment: Thanks Lukasz I tried this before too although it gives me the two purchase dates for the customer I'm trying to get  the following so that I have duplicated rows for each customer. Duplicates row of CustomerID1 and Customer 2 with the purchasedate.  (view results above on original post)